# Why doesn't Visual Studio open file in "Start without debugging" mode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int a = 0;
    int e = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int o = 0;
    int u = 0;

    std::ifstream file("myfile.txt", std::ifstream::in);

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while (file.get(ch))
        {
            if (ch == 'a')
                a++;
            if (ch == 'e')
                e++;
            if (ch == 'i')
                i++;
            if (ch == 'o')
                o++;
            if (ch == 'u')
                u++;
        }

        std::cout << "Repetitions of a: " << a << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Repetitions of e: " << e << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Repetitions of i: " << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Repetitions of o: " << o << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Repetitions of u: " << u << std::endl;

    }

    else std::cout << "Error in opening file" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to make a simple c++ program to count occurrences of vowel letters in a txt file, using Visual Studio 2015.
This code works in Debug Mode but when i start it without debugging (from inside Visual Studio) it's doesn't open the file. Why does it happen and how can i fix it??
The txt file is in the same directory of the program

I haven't got the problem when i use the full path e.g. Y:\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\stream\stream\myfile.txt  but however i would like to know why it doesn't work with the relative path e.g. myfile.txt

Thanks!

Comment: The text file is in the _Debug_ folder isn't it?

Comment: It should be in the same folder as the project file unless you changed the settings for your project.

Comment: In MSVS the text file needs to be in the same place the source files are.  Where is your text file?

Comment: What do you mean by "run it without debugging" exactly? Starting it from inside of Visual Studio IDE without debugging? Or starting it from outside of IDE?

Comment: starting it from inside VS without debugging

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio changes the "Working Directory" of the program depending on how you execute it. If you run it from within the Visual Studio IDE, it will use the Source Directory as its working directory by default (this can be changed in the project properties). If you don't, the program will use the directory from which the program was executed.

For safety, you could try keeping copies of the file both in the source directory and the target directory (where the Executable gets created) to ensure it has no trouble finding it.

Comment: I copied my file in target directory (where there is .exe) but i still got the same problem..what is source directory? The one where there is also the .vcxproj file? If it's so, myfile.txt is already there as well.
Is there a way to choose the working directory in "start without debugging mode" ?
Thank for your answers!

Comment: @Ale The "Source Directory" is where your .h and .cpp files are (normally) located. It might be helpful if you add screenshots of your directory structure to the question, to allow us to see how things are laid out, and look for discrepancies.

Comment: @Ale Also [look into using `_getcwd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y.aspx) to track down the working directory. No point guessing where it is if you can ask and then adjust accordingly.

Comment: Sorry i'm not able to post images, but i put myfile.txt in 3 places ("stream" is the name of my project):
.........\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\stream\Debug
.........\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\stream\Release
.........\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\stream\stream